# GUI not updating despite use of validate()

Tags: java, swing, validation, user-interface, connect

Here is a Connect Four program I'm making. So far, I'm able to add checkers to empty (eligible) slots, alternating red and black each time. My code may be quite inefficient, as this is my first swing program. However, my only major problem is that I can't really get the GUI to update after the empty slots are clicked on. I tried validate(), but that didn't appear to do anything. Links to the images used in the program can be found below. Thanks so much for your help!

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new GameFrame();
                    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass()
                            .getResource("675 x 588 Connect Four.png"))));
                    frame.addSlots();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    static GameFrame frame;
    private static Icon slotForButton;
    public static JButton slotButton;
    static private JButton[] slot = new JButton[42];
    static private String[] slotColor = new String[42];
    static boolean turn = true;
    static boolean legitClick;
    static String slotClicked;
    static int slotNum;
    static Container gamePane;

    public GameFrame() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 685, 622);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        super.setTitle("Connect Four by Joel Christophel");
    }

    void addSlots() {
        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
        gamePane = getContentPane();
        gamePane.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6));
        int counter = 0;

        for (JButton e : slot) {
            slot[counter] = makeSlot("white");
            slot[counter].setBorderPainted(false);
            slot[counter].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            slot[counter].setFocusPainted(false);
            slot[counter].setActionCommand(counter + "");
            slotColor[counter] = "white";

            slot[counter].addActionListener(bh);
            add(slot[counter]);

            counter++;
        }
    }

    static JButton makeSlot(String color) {

        if (color.equals("white")) {
            slotForButton = new ImageIcon(
                    GameFrame.class.getResource("Space.png"));
        }

        else if (color.equals("red")) {
            slotForButton = new ImageIcon(
                    GameFrame.class.getResource("Red Checker.png"));
        }

        else if (color.equals("black")) {
            slotForButton = new ImageIcon(
                    GameFrame.class.getResource("Black Checker.png"));
        }

        slotButton = new JButton(slotForButton);

        return slotButton;
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            slotClicked = e.getActionCommand();

            GameFrame.legitClick(slotClicked);
        }

    }

    private static void changeTurn() {
        turn = !turn; // true is red's turn; false is black's
    }

    private static void legitClick(String slotClicked1) {
        legitClick = false;

        slotClicked = slotClicked1;
        Scanner numScan = new Scanner(slotClicked);
        slotNum = numScan.nextInt();

        try {
            if (!slotColor[slotNum + 7].equals("white")&&slotColor[slotNum].equals("white")) {
                legitClick = true;
            }
        }

        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException t) {

            if (slotColor[slotNum].equals("white")) {
                legitClick = true;
            }
        }

        if (legitClick == true) {
            if (turn == true) {
                slot[slotNum] = makeSlot("red");
                slotColor[slotNum] = "red";
                System.out.println("Put " + slotColor[slotNum] + " checker     in slot number " + slotNum + ".");
            }

            else if (turn == false) {
                slot[slotNum] = makeSlot("black");
                slotColor[slotNum] = "black";
                System.out.println("Put " + slotColor[slotNum] + " checker      in slot number " + slotNum + ".");
            }

            gamePane.validate();
            GameFrame.changeTurn();
        }
        System.out.println(turn);
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cNB3.png 675 x 588 Connect Four.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oX7A.png Black Checker.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdF7u.png Red Checker.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNT61.png Space.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thingies, it appears to me that you doing wrong in your code.

- First do check the condition that you specifying inside your
  **legitClick()** method, no matter when you click, it always returns false (legitClick). Hence no change will appear to the view.
- It appears that you creating a new **JButton** inside a `makeSlot()`, which is not exactly what you want, you simply have to change the **Icon** for the respective **JButton** instead of creating a new one.

I had modified the code a bit, inside the `makeSlot()` method and `legitClick()` method, though you have to change the logic yourself to actually make it work as you wanted, since I don't know how checkers work :(

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new GameFrame();
                    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass()
                            .getResource("/image/675 x 588 Connect Four.png"))));
                    frame.addSlots();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    static GameFrame frame;
    private static Icon slotForButton;
    public static JButton slotButton;
    static private JButton[] slot = new JButton[42];
    static private String[] slotColor = new String[42];
    static boolean turn = true;
    static boolean legitClick;
    static String slotClicked;
    static int slotNum;
    static Container gamePane;

    public GameFrame() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 685, 622);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        super.setTitle("Connect Four by Joel Christophel");
    }

    void addSlots() {
        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
        gamePane = getContentPane();
        gamePane.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6));

        for (int counter = 0; counter < slot.length; counter++) {
            // Added by me.
            slot[counter] = new JButton();
            slot[counter].setIcon(makeSlot("white", counter));
            slot[counter].setBorderPainted(false);
            slot[counter].setContentAreaFilled(false);
            slot[counter].setFocusPainted(false);
            slot[counter].setActionCommand(counter + "");
            slotColor[counter] = "white";

            slot[counter].addActionListener(bh);
            add(slot[counter]);

            //counter++;
        }
    }

    static Icon makeSlot(String color, int index) {

        if (color.equals("white")) {
            slotForButton = new ImageIcon(
                    GameFrame.class.getResource("/image/Space.png"));
        }

        else if (color.equals("red")) {
            slotForButton = new ImageIcon(
                    GameFrame.class.getResource("/image/Red Checker.png"));
        }

        else if (color.equals("black")) {
            slotForButton = new ImageIcon(
                    GameFrame.class.getResource("/image/Black Checker.png"));
        }

        //slot[index].setIcon(slotForButton);

        return slotForButton;
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            slotClicked = e.getActionCommand();

            GameFrame.legitClick(slotClicked);
        }

    }

    private static void changeTurn() {
        turn = !turn; // true is red's turn; false is black's
    }

    private static void legitClick(String slotClicked1) {
        legitClick = false;

        slotClicked = slotClicked1;
        Scanner numScan = new Scanner(slotClicked);
        slotNum = numScan.nextInt();

        try {
            if (slotColor[slotNum + 7].equals("white")&&slotColor[slotNum].equals("white")) {
                legitClick = true;
            }
        }

        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException t) {

            if (slotColor[slotNum].equals("white")) {
                legitClick = true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * This variable is used to tell
         * makeSlot that the JButton at
         * this index is pressed. So
         * simply change the Icon for this
         * JButton, instead of adding a new 
         * JButton.
         */
        int index = Integer.parseInt(slotClicked1);

        if (legitClick == true) {
            if (turn == true) {
                slot[index].setIcon(makeSlot("red", index));
                slotColor[slotNum] = "red";
                System.out.println("Put " + slotColor[slotNum] + " checker     in slot number " + slotNum + ".");
            }

            else if (turn == false) {
                slot[index].setIcon(makeSlot("black", index));
                slotColor[slotNum] = "black";
                System.out.println("Put " + slotColor[slotNum] + " checker      in slot number " + slotNum + ".");
            }

            //gamePane.validate();
            GameFrame.changeTurn();
        }
        System.out.println(turn);
    }

}
```

Comment: And I forgot one very important thingy, don't use that many static things in your code, less you really wanted to create one Factory Class. Though the intend of the instructions doesn't specify as such, hence stay away from static thingy as much as you can. This is really not a good practice to introduce so many static thingies in your program for no reason.

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel : You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is to add this line of code after `gamePane.validate();`

`gamePane.repaint();`

The correct answer is to learn how to use [SwingWorker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker)

Comment: It would be worth a check, but you might be able to get away without needing to call `validate`